# uWSGI and Python > 3.4

Tags: django, uwsgi, python-3.6

I have a django project currently running with the following configuration:

- Debian 8
- Python 3.4
- uWSGI in emperor mode

I installed Python 3.6.1 from source and created a new virtual environment with python 3.6 (I use virtualenvwrapper), but I seem to have some trouble getting the project to start up with uwsgi.

Config file is as follows:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = python3
project = %n
module = myapp.wsgi:application
home = path_to_new_env
socket = /var/run/uwsgi-%n.sock
chdir = path_to_new_env/myapp/myapp
processes = 4
max-requests = 5000
chmod-socket = 666
chown-socket = user:user
master = True
vacuum = True
logto = /var/log/%n_LOG.log
buffer-size = 32768
```

I was under the impression that the `python3` plugin would include support for python 3.6, but the log indicates that the Python 3.4.x interpreter is still being used.

In my list of installed uwsgi plugins, I see support for python 2, 3 and 3.4 but nothing more. I'm not sure what needs to be done to have the correct interpreter set on startup.

Any advice would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I've tried building a uwsgi plugin for python 3.6:

```
root@app:~# PYTHON=python3.6 uwsgi --build-plugin "/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python python36"
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin from /root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python ***
[gcc -pthread] python36_plugin.so
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/python_plugin.c: In function ‘uwsgi_python_atexit’:
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/python_plugin.c:380:11: error: ‘struct uwsgi_server’ has no member named ‘skip_atexit_teardown’
  if (uwsgi.skip_atexit_teardown)
           ^
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/python_plugin.c: At top level:
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/python_plugin.c:2018:2: error: unknown field ‘worker’ specified in initializer
  .worker = uwsgi_python_worker,
  ^
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/python_plugin.c:2018:2: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/python_plugin.c:2018:2: error: (near initialization for ‘python36_plugin.exception_class’) [-Werror]
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/python_plugin.c:2018:2: error: initialized field overwritten [-Werror=override-init]
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/python_plugin.c:2018:2: error: (near initialization for ‘python36_plugin.exception_class’) [-Werror=override-init]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.c: In function ‘py_uwsgi_spooler_get_task’:
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.c:2107:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘uwsgi_spooler_read_header’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if (uwsgi_spooler_read_header(task_path, spool_fd, &uh) ||
  ^
/root/uwsgi-2.0.15/plugins/python/uwsgi_pymodule.c:2108:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘uwsgi_spooler_read_content’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   uwsgi_spooler_read_content(spool_fd, spool_buf, &body, &body_len, &uh, &task_stat)) {
   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
*** unable to build python36 plugin ***
```

Comment: Not a solution, but an alternative strategy that might be appropriate, if you don't actually require python3.6: use a python3.4 virtualenvironment

Answer (score 6):

I've recently came up with a solution to python3.6 apps with [uwsgi](/questions/tagged/uwsgi) server.

```
wget https://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-latest.tar.gz
tar -xvzf uwsgi-latest.tar.gz

mv uwsgi-2.0.17 uwsgi
cd uwsgi
make PROFILE=nolang # no language defaults allows flexibility for python versions

PYTHON=python3.6 # or --> PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6

./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python36"
mv python36_plugin.so plugins/python
cd ..
sudo mv uwsgi /usr/local
sudo ln -s /usr/local/uwsgi/uwsgi /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
```

Then, you can use it in configuration files as follows:

```
[uwsgi]

plugins-dir = /usr/local/uwsgi/plugins/python
plugin = python36
```

Mimic this process for any other python version you'd like to have available on the uwsgi server.
More help [here](https://serverfault.com/a/916780/345808).

Comment: I tried this but it still says it is using python 2.

Comment: Maybe you missed something dude. Restart the service, the console, `make PROFILE=nolang` or who knows...

Comment: Thank you very much! Had a helluva time getting Flask 2.0.0 to work with uWSGI and Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04.x. Anything from segfaults from the python36 plugin to uWSGI being unable to import flask(!). Following the above steps fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1) Download uwsgi source tarball

2) Follow build instructions [here](http://uwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html#bonus-multiple-python-versions-for-the-same-uwsgi-binary)

Note that for python3.6, you need to configure python with the `--enable-shared` flag as well as declare an extra environment variable before building the uWsgi plugin: `export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC"`

3) Install new uwsgi binary with supported plugins: `cp uwsgi /usr/local/bin/`