# uwsgi can't build plugin.so for python3.6

Tags: python, uwsgi

I was trying to build uwsgi+django server. I need to build uwsgi python36_plugin.so for python3.6 using this command:

```
make PROFILE=nolang
PYTHON=python3 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python36"
```

It didn't work:

```
 [root@izuf64a9gck81cz uwsgi-2.0.15]# PYTHON=python ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python36"
*** uWSGI building and linking plugin from plugins/python ***
[gcc -pthread] python36_plugin.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/python3/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/python3/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** unable to build python36 plugin ***
```

When i use build python2.7 version,it turns out right

```
PYTHON=python2.7 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python27"
```

Comment: do you solve this problem?

Comment: no, i got to use python3.4 to build my app

Answer (score 1):

My problem is I have two version of python 3, the default python3 is python3.4, and the second one is python3.6, and I want to use python3.6 for some of my django project so I need to build the plugins and I got same problem you got.

It took me couple hours to solved this issue. Here is what I did from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44663383/9830077):

1. Reconfigure  my python3.6

`cd Python-3.6.4/
./configure --enable-shared --enable-optimizations --prefix=/usr/local LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/lib"`

2. Get in to your uwsgi folder and try to build again

`PYTHON=python3.6 ./uwsgi --build-plugin "plugins/python python36"`

Goodluck! May it solve your prob too!